# how to auto reload table view cells of presented table view controller from app delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uilocalnotification, presentviewcontroller

I am creating an app which triggers a local notification every 30 seconds once and when I tap on the notification it opens a table view controller. 
This table view controller has  a badge on it's tableview cells to display notification count(like no. of messages displayed against a contact in whatsapp in green icon). If a notification arrives when the app is active(i.e.with table view controller on screen),the notification count should be updated on the badges of cells. I did this by writing the following code in **didReceiveLocalNotification** method of my app delegate:

```
var root = self.window!.rootViewController as ViewController
let main: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var setview = main.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableview") as TableViewController

if application.applicationState==UIApplicationState.Active
    {
        TableViewController().tableView.reloadData()
        root.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //I don't want to use this. Only badges should be updated
        root.presentViewController(setview, animated:true , completion: nil)   
}
```

Comment: reloadData should be enough, but are you actually counting the notifications? Is there a +1 somewhere?

Comment: Should't it be `setview.tableView.reloadData()`? TableViewController(). looks odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I tap on the notification it opens a table view controller.

So why not reload your table only when you tap on the notification?

You should populate your cell array on ViewDidAppear, and then display the updated cells (with your badges) in your UITableView.

Or (other idea) - when your UITableView is still open, why not use a NSNotification to update your TableView?

Something like:

In your TableView Class:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadTable:", name:"ReloadHandler", object: nil)

    func reloadTable(notification: NSNotification){
       .... populate your cell data array
       ... reload your table

     }
```

// And in your Main View Controller (where you receive the UIApplicationState)

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReloadHandler", object: false)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it by trying the second method